# ElasticSearch Bool Filter with a Phrase (instead of a single word/tag)

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastic search, this filter

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "term": {
        "article.title": "google"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Properly returns articles with "google" in the title.

However,

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "term": {
        "article.title": "google earth"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does not return any results, despite the fact that there are articles with the exact words "google earth" in the  title. I would like it to do so.

The full query:

```
{
  "size": 200,
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "article.title": "google maps"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "range": {
      "created_date": {
        "from": "2013-01-11T02:14:03.352Z"
      }
    }
  }]
}
}
```

As you can see, I don't have a "query" -- just a filter, size, and range. So I take it that ElasticSearch is using the default analyzer...?

What am I misunderstanding?

---

**EDIT:** For those looking for the solution, here is my filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "must_match": {
          "article.title": "google earth"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Node that (1) we wrapped the bool filter  with "query" and (2) the "term" changed to a "must_match", which causes the entire phrase to be matched (as opposed to "match" which would search the article.title with a standard analyzer on google earth).

The full query looks like this:

```
{
  "size": 200,
  "filter": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "must_match": {
            "article.title": "google earth"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

FWIW, the reason I have this condition within the "filter" field (as opposed to using a standard query) is that sometimes I want to use a "must_not" instead of a "must_not", and sometimes I also add other elements to the query.

Comment: What does your analyzer look like for article.title?  If you are analyzing the field with anything other than "Keyword", that field will be tokenized into [google] and [earth], which will make it faila  term match.

Comment: Hm, is the article from the query carried over to the filter? I've updated my question to illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elasticsearch isn't using an analyzer at all, because you have used the [`term` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-query.html), which looks for exact terms.

Your `title` field IS analyzed (unless you have specified otherwise), so `"google earth"` will have been indexed as the two terms `["google","earth"]`.  That's why the `term` query for `"google"` works, but the `term` query for `"google earth"` doesn't - that EXACT term does not exist.

If you use a [`match` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query.html) instead, then your query terms will be analyzed before searching.

Answer (score 1):

Using Elasticsearch 5.4.2., my solution evolved to be the following one:

```
{"query": {
     "bool": {
         "must": {
             "match_phrase": {
                 "article.title": "google earth"}}}}}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling upon this more recently, be advised that a more concise way to represent

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"must_match":{"article.title":"google earth"}}}}}
```

is with

```
{"query":{"match_phrase":{"article.title":"google earth"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by exploding the passed phrase, so just changing.

```
{"bool":{"must":{"term":{"article.title":"google earth"}}}}
```

to

```
{"bool":{"must":{"term":{"article.title":["google", "earth"]}}}}
```

It's not pretty and might be too slow if you have a lot of queries going on, but it works.

**NOTE, I just found out this will also return any results with either "google" or "earth".**